# Аватар двигает комментарии

Tags: дефект, аватар-пользователя

Подробный показ аватара двигает раздел комментариев (точнее все что снизу аватара). А должно?
Просто то, что блок с подробностями накладывается сверху сайта, показал странным эффект от аватара.

[image]